# get specific value in each group and add it as new column in each group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to have something like this:

---

dataframe:

```
 col1            col2             col3
A               'aa'            date1
A               'aa'            date2
A               'aa'            date3
A               'bb'            date4
B               'aa'            date5
B               'bb'            date6
B               'aa'            date7
```

output:

```
  col1            col2             col3        col4       
    A               'aa'            date1        date4
    A               'aa'            date2        date4 
    A               'aa'            date3        date4
    A               'bb'            date4        date4
    B               'aa'            date5        date6
    B               'bb'            date6        date6
    B               'aa'            date7        date6
```

I want to group by col1 and based on value in col2 get col3 and add a new column as col4 and set it as this value of col3

'aa' and 'bb' are examples so I can't use sort...I should compare it with a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are only one `bb` values per groups filter them and [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new column:

```
s = df[df['col2'].eq('bb')].set_index('col1')['col3']
#if possible multiple values per groups
#s = df[df['col2'].eq('bb')].drop_duplicates('col1').set_index('col1')['col3']
df['col4'] = df['col1'].map(s)
print (df)
  col1 col2   col3   col4
0    A   aa  date1  date4
1    A   aa  date2  date4
2    A   aa  date3  date4
3    A   bb  date4  date4
4    B   aa  date5  date6
5    B   bb  date6  date6
6    B   aa  date7  date6
```

Another idea with left join in `merge`:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['col2'].eq('bb'),['col1','col3']].rename(columns={'col3':'col4'})
```

If duplicated `bb` values per groups:

```
df1 = (df.loc[df['col2'].eq('bb'),['col1','col3']]
         .drop_duplicates('col1')
         .rename(columns={'col3':'col4'}))

print (df1)
  col1   col4
3    A  date4
5    B  date6

df = df.merge(df1, on='col1', how='left')
print (df)
  col1 col2   col3   col4
0    A   aa  date1  date4
1    A   aa  date2  date4
2    A   aa  date3  date4
3    A   bb  date4  date4
4    B   aa  date5  date6
5    B   bb  date6  date6
6    B   aa  date7  date6
```

Comment: Thank's. But It will take a long time. Is there a better solution?

Comment: @faraa - filtering per groups is slowier, so cannot be used here. Added another solution with `merge`

Comment: Thank's... But it seems to add some new rows to my data!

Comment: @faraa - there is used `df.loc[df['col2'].eq('bb'),['col1','col3']]` ? filtered by mask and by `col1` and `col3`

Comment: Yes...But maybe I have this problem because I have more than one 'bb' for some groups :-?

Comment: @faraa - Then is possible use `df1 = (df.loc[df['col2'].eq('bb'),['col1','col3']]
         .drop_duplicates('col1')
         .rename(columns={'col3':'col4'}))
`

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```py
df=df.sort_values("col2", ascending=False).set_index("col1")

df["col4"]=df.groupby("col1")["col3"].first()

df=df.reset_index(drop=False)
```

Outputs:

```py
  col1 col2   col3   col4
0    A   bb  date4  date4
1    B   bb  date6  date6
2    A   aa  date1  date4
3    A   aa  date2  date4
4    A   aa  date3  date4
5    B   aa  date5  date6
6    B   aa  date7  date6
```

**Edit**
IIUC - to get `col4` the value from `col3`, grouped by `col1` for where `col2=="bb"`

Try:

```py
df=df.set_index("col1")

df["col4"]=df.loc[df["col2"]=="bb"].groupby("col1")["col3"].first()

df=df.reset_index(drop=False)
```

Comment: Not sure I follow, what do you mean?

Comment: Thank's. But 'aa' and 'bb' are examples so I can't use sort...I should compare it with a value.

Comment: So you want to get for each group first ```col3``` where ```col2="bb"``` that's what you mean by compare to value?